# TRIAC Pulse driver for Spot Welder (help needed with programming)

Tags: c++, power, arduino-leonardo, prototype

I have designed and built a transformer driver board for my spot welder. It is powered from mains electricity (230 V) and consists of the following segments: triac drive and protection, zero cross detection, controller input, connections. The board operates correctly when voltage is manually applied. However, I'm not able to make it work with Arduino.

[image: Main board shematic.]
What I want it to do is:

1. Read the potentiometer(R10), and assign to it value a phase angle, at which triac is going to receive pulse to turn on.
2. Read Potentiometer (R9), and assigned to it value number of pulses(1-100) for a triac,
3. Read switch (Power_pulse) that when high start triac firing procedure (angle and duration determined by pots)
4. I have an I2C display 16x4 that(can be driven directly from SCL and SDA on Leonardo) I might use to display welding parameters(optional goal) 
   The code I found on "electronoobs.com"

   ```
      int detectado = 0;
       int valor=0;
        int last_CH1_state = 0;

      void setup() {


     PCICR |= (1 << PCIE0);    //enable PCMSK0 scan                                                 
     PCMSK0 |= (1 << PCINT0);  //Set pin D8 trigger an interrupt on state change. Input from optocoupler
     pinMode(3,OUTPUT);        //Define D3 as output for the DIAC pulse

   }

   void loop() {
      //Read the value of the pot and map it from 10 to 10.000 us. AC frequency is 50Hz, so period is 20ms. We want to control the power
      //of each half period, so the maximum is 10ms or 10.000us. In my case I've maped it up to 7.200us since 10.000 was too much

      valor = map(analogRead(A0),0,1024,7200,10);
       if (detectado)
       {
         delayMicroseconds(valor); //This delay controls the power
         digitalWrite(3,HIGH);
         delayMicroseconds(100);
         digitalWrite(3,LOW);
         detectado=0;
       } 
   }




   //This is the interruption routine
   //----------------------------------------------

   ISR(PCINT0_vect){
     /////////////////////////////////////               //Input from optocoupler
     if(PINB & B00000001){                               //We make an AND with the pin state register, We verify if pin 8 is HIGH???
       if(last_CH1_state == 0){                          //If the last state was 0, then we have a state change...
         detectado=1;                                    //We haev detected a state change!
       }
     }
     else if(last_CH1_state == 1){                       //If pin 8 is LOW and the last state was HIGH then we have a state change      
       detectado=1;                                      //We haev detected a state change!
       last_CH1_state = 0;                               //Store the  current state into the last state for the next loop
       }
   }
   ```

Finally the question: What do I need to add to this code to make it work in my application?

PS.  Issues regarding safety are addressed by another board that have fuse and over voltage protection.

PPS. I have 5V supply dedicated to driving the board and Arduino.

```
enter code here
void setup() {

}

 int faza=0;
 int cykle=1;
 bool wcisniety;

  void loop() {

    faza=20000 * analogRead(2) / 255;// Pot 1
    cykle=100 * analogRead(3) / 255; //Pot2

  if(digitalRead(4) && (! wcisniety))// if cheacks for button pres to activate function
    {zgrzewaj();} 

   wcisniety=digitalRead(4);

   }


 void zgrzewaj(){

   while (digitalRead(0)){

    }

  for (int i=0; i < cykle;i++){

delayMicroseconds(faza);

digitalWrite(1,HIGH);

delay(10-faza/1000);

digitalWrite(1,LOW);// fireing TRIAC 
 }
}
```

This is what i come up  with. While it looks simple and proprly build still dont hav any output.
All coments appreciated.

Comment: Link to project page at electronoobs: http://www.electronoobs.com/eng_circuitos_tut20.php @Pioter, the arduino leonardo has an other microcontroller than the arduino uno and at electronoobs they use an arduino uno.

Comment: The higher level functions do the same, for example digitalWrite( 13, HIGH). Everything below that is different.